# How do I directly trigger a download window for a downloaded S3 file in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I still don't know very well about aws s3 storage, but I can already do the basic operations of listing / uploading / downloading objects using nuget awssdks.

However, when downloading an object, I have to create a file on my web server and then make the file available to my user.

It seems to me that I don't know how to perform the direct download to the client.

Is this possible ? If yes, which way to do this?

How to simply transform my current source code for direct download in S3 ?

Thank you very much for guidance.

```
private void DOWFile(string pFileDir, string pFileName, string pDescription)
{
    //Armazena o path do arquivo
    string lFilePath = pFileDir + pFileName;
    //Verifica se o arquivo existe
    if (File.Exists(lFilePath))
    {
        //Limpa o objeto de resposta
        Response.Clear();
        //Limpa o nome do arquivo
        if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Firefox")) pDescription = TFileInfo.CONVERTToFileName(pDescription);   
        //Adiciona o cabeçalho do donwload
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(pDescription) + "\"");
        //Seta o tipo do arquivo
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        //Passa a referência do arquivo
        Response.WriteFile(lFilePath);
        //Executa o download do arquivo
        Response.Flush();
        //Finaliza o processamento
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        //Mostra a mensagem de Erro
        SETErrorInfo(new TErrorInfo(-1, "DOWFile", TErrorInfo.ErrFileNotFound, "FileNotFound - " + lFilePath, false, true, false, true, false, TErrorInfo.TErrType.etLogic));
    }
}

public bool FileDownS3(string pLocalPath, string pFileNameS3)
    {
        IAmazonS3 lClient_Aws = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        TransferUtility lUtility = new TransferUtility(lClient_Aws);

        string filename = pLocalPath + pFileNameS3;
        FileStream fs = File.Create(filename);
        fs.Close();


        lUtility.Download(filename, gBucketName, pFileNameS3);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I can't see any S3 code?

Comment: Are you asking how to read the file and then download the file in your browser?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary 

`code`
        public bool FileDownS3(string pLocalPath, string pFileNameS3)
        {
            IAmazonS3 lClient_Aws = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            TransferUtility lUtility = new TransferUtility(lClient_Aws);

            string filename = pLocalPath + pFileNameS3;
            FileStream fs = File.Create(filename);
            fs.Close();


            lUtility.Download(filename, gBucketName, pFileNameS3);

            return true;
        }`code`

Comment: @FabioAlvesFrancelino Please add the code to the question, thanks :)

Comment: @smac2020 Yes, how to download the file direct to the client, without creating the file in my web server.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary i've done this

Comment: I want to tirgger the download window instead of save the file in a path in my webserver.

Comment: @FabioAlvesFrancelino So can you confirm that the S3 code is fine? And that your question is on how to trigger the window?

Comment: @FabioAlvesFrancelino I've added an answer with both S3 code as well as the file download just in case :)

Answer (score 1):

**You need to return a `File` object from your handler action, created from a `MemoryStream` without saving it anywhere locally.**

To do so, you first need to get the S3 object in the form of a `MemoryStream`.

Pass the `bucketName` & `key` for your S3 object to [`AmazonS3Client.GetObjectAsync(...)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3GetObjectAsyncStringStringCancellationToken.html), which returns a response of type [`GetObjectResponse`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TGetObjectResponse.html).

`GetObjectResponse` has a property called `ResponseStream`.

This is a [stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream) object which inherits from `Amazon.S3.Model.StreamResponse`.

You can then copy this to a `MemoryStream`:

```
GetObjectResponse response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(bucketName, keyName);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
    responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
}
```

Once copied, return converted to a `File` in your controller action.

**Make sure to also set a *filename*** (third parameter to `File(...)` so that the browser can determine the file type for the download:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadS3File() {
    ...
    return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "filename.pdf");
}
```

This should trigger a download for an object downloaded from Amazon S3.

Comment: Excellent, I will implement your suggestion and return to tell you if it worked

Comment: Can't find AmazonS3Client.GetObjectAsync, I understood perfectly how to store the file in memory in an object and then trigger it on download, but I'm still confused on how to use the S3 classes basically because I can't find the function you suggested, I'll keep searching.

Comment: In this solution I am also concerned about concurrent sessions and server memory management, how many simultaneous users will be able to download until memory is full, a limitation of my webapp is the maximum file size of 100MB which can minimize this issue, but I have this concern

Comment: That is on the actual client, it’s not a static method - for you it’s `lClient_Aws.Get…`